# При считывании из файла "я" == EOF?

Tags: c, файлы

Задание такое: посчитать количество повторений букв в текстовом файле на украинском языке. Написал функцию, но что-то идёт не так, совсем запутался, не понимаю, в чём дело. Например, в файле записано имя "Петрова Настя". Количество повторений символа "я" равно 0. Возможно, "я" с кодом -1 в ANSI принимается программой как EOF. Помогите, пожалуйста, а то голову ломаю, впервые работаю с файлами в си((

```
char alphabetlow[MAX] = {'а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'ґ', 'д', 'е', 'є', 'ж', 'з', 'и', 'і', 'ї', 'й', 
'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ь', 'ю', 'я' };
char alphabetup[MAX] = {'А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Ґ', 'Д', 'Е', 'Є', 'Ж', 'З', 'И', 'І', 'Ї', 'Й',
'К', 'Л', 'М', 'Н', 'О', 'П', 'Р', 'С', 'Т', 'У', 'Ф', 'Х', 'Ц', 'Ч', 'Ш', 'Щ', 'Ь', 'Ю', 'Я' };
char checked[MAX]; // уже перевірені літери
int numbers[MAX]; // кількість повторень відповідних за індексом літер

void AverageProbability(FILE* file) 
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int m = 0; // кількість літер у файлі (без повторень)
    int n = 0; // загальна кількість літер
    int all = 0; // загальна кількість символів
    int repeat = 0;
    int comp;
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
        int issymb = 0;
        int count = 1; // кількість повторень певної літери
        for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
            if ((char)c == (char)alphabetup[i] || (char)c == (char)alphabetlow[i]) {
                issymb = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (issymb == 1) {
            for (j = 0; j < MAX; j++) {
                if (alphabetlow[i] == checked[j]) {
                    repeat = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (repeat == 0) {
                checked[m] = alphabetlow[i];
                while ((comp = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
                    if ((char)comp == (char)alphabetlow[i] || (char)comp == (char)alphabetup[i]) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                numbers[i] = count;
                m++;
            }
            n++;
        }
        all++;
        fseek(file, all, SEEK_SET);
    }
    printf(" К-сть букв - %d\n", n);
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        printf(" Буква [%c] - %d\n", alphabetlow[i], numbers[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Какова сверхзадача? Что-то очень странный у вас код...

Comment: Потому что вы зачем-то преобразуете `int` в `char`, в итоге код символа `я` превращается из int 255 в char -1, а -1 это и есть EOF

Comment: @Harry Вообще нужно посчитать вероятность появления букв украинского алфавита (независимо от регистра) - количество повторений определенной буквы поделить на общее количество букв в файле

Comment: @andreymal Я сравниваю считанный символ из файла с char-элементами массивов alphabetlow и alphabetup, думал, для этого нужно считанный символ преобразовать в char. Пробовал так как вы говорите и тогда количество повторений всех букв получается 0

Comment: Да, его нужно преобразовать в char, но **после** проверки на EOF, а вы тут преобразуете перед проверкой

Comment: @andreymal исправил код, я правильно вас понял? Подозреваю, что не так, потому что я все равно не считается :D

Comment: На общее количество ВСЕХ букв (включая латинские, например, знаки препинания) или только украинские же?

Comment: @Harry на общее количество украинских букв в файле

Comment: @Harry при считывании из файла код символа "П" 208, а в массиве код -49, это из-за разных кодировок? Текстовый файл у меня на ANSI

Comment: Лучше переводить все в `unsigned char`, потому как `char` может быть и знаковым... См. мой дополненный ответ - именно поэтому я все и привожу к `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 4):

```
char c;
while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
```

А правильно -

```
int c;
while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
```

Не уверен, впрочем, что это все неприятности.

Попробуйте этот код (только не забывайте, что файл должен быть в соответствующей кодировке):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const char * alphabetlow = {"абвгґдеєжзиіїйклмнопрстуфхцчшщьюя" };
const char * alphabetup  = {"АБВГҐДЕЄЖЗИІЇЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЬЮЯ" };

unsigned char isUkrUp(char c)
{
    if (strchr(alphabetup,c)) return c;
    char * a = strchr(alphabetlow,c);
    if (a == NULL) return 0;
    return alphabetup[a-alphabetlow];
}

void AverageProbability(FILE* file)
{

    int total = 0;
    int count[256] = {0}; // Объем небольшой, а возни куда меньше :)
    for(int ch = fgetc(file); ch != EOF; ch = fgetc(file))
    {
        unsigned char c = isUkrUp((char)ch);
        if (c == 0) continue;
        total++;
        count[c]++;
    }
    printf(" К-сть букв - %d\n", total);
    for(const unsigned char * a =
        (const unsigned char *)alphabetup; *a; ++a)
    {
        printf(" Буква [%c] - %d\n", *a, count[*a]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    FILE* f = fopen("data","rt");
    AverageProbability(f);
    fclose(f);
}
```

Теоретически, если правильно работает локализация, то можно и еще проще, но...

Comment: Интересно, а как в украинских программах решают проблему с одинаковым глифом и разными кодами для ascii `Ii` (коды в сp1251 0x49, 0x69) и cyrillic `Ii` (коды в cp1251 0xb2, 0xb3)?

Comment: @avp, а в чём проблема? Почему наличие русской `Аа` и латинской `Aa` тебя не смущает?

Comment: @Qwertiy, наверное в том, что я не представляю украинскую раскладку клавиатуры. Там при переключении в cyrillic где-то появляются украинские `Ii` (аналогично `ёЁ`, которые я практически не использую)?

Comment: @avp, у меня на клавиатуре вот такое есть: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzYVM.jpg и https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqRUn.jpg - думаю, это как раз украинский. Но как этим пользоваться, я понятия не имею. Может как для ₽ надо вводить Правый Alt + 8? Хм.. А хвостатого Г у меня нет...

Comment: @Qwertiy, вот я и думаю, что некоторые пользователи (на моей клавиатуре твоих `Ii` нету)  вынуждены  вводить латинские буквы. Понятно, что к учебной задаче это не относится, просто интересно, насколько принято в серьезных программах пытаться распознать и исправить такое

Comment: @avp, думаю, проще выучить расположение трёх кнопок, чем каждый раз переключать раскладку, не? А вообще, я к Украине не имею никакого отношения, так что понятия не имею, как они печатают. Просто случайно купил такую клавиатуру)))

Comment: @avp На украинской клавиатуре - на клавишах для русских букв, отсутствующих в украинском языке (ы - i, ъ - ї, э - є). Где-то там и хвостатая г, точно не скажу - но она как в русском языке ять :) - так что можно и код запомнить для пяти слов :). А кстати, никто не знает, как бы в винде дописать что-то, что позволяло бы одним щелчком добавлять в систему украинскую *клавиатуру* и убирать ее? А то иногда требуется, а ставить-убивать через языковую панель - тот еще геморрой... А вот сейчас и задам вопрос...

Comment: @Harry, понял, спасибо!